# ifstreaming a file not working properly. Here is the code

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, ifstream

In my program i am storing data given by the user in a .txt file with the help of ofstream.
I am using setw() to ensure proper gaping between the entered data and i am storing the data of a user in a single row. Here is the code for that:

```
string n,mn,fn;
int a;
cout<<"Enter your full name: ";
getline(cin, n);
cin.ignore();
cout<<"Father name: ";
getline(cin, fn);
cin.ignore();
cout<<"Mother name: ";
getline(cin, mn);
cin.ignore();
cout<<"Enter your age: ";
cin>>a;
ofstream file("my.txt",ios::app);
file<<left<<setw(50)<<n<<setw(50)<<a<<setw(50)<<fn<<setw(50)<<mn<<endl;
file.close();
```

My .txt file saves data properly with proper spacing as:

```
parth kumar        12         jack worn        juli zeel
standly duke       19         shane roger      zoya khan
```

now I want to ifstream this data in my same program. I wrote the following code to ifstream only first row. Here is the code:

```
string fn,mn,n;
int a;
ifstream file("my.txt");
file>>left>>setw(50)>>n;
file>>setw(50)>>a;
file>>setw(50)>>fn;
file>>setw(50)>>mn
cout<<n<<"   "<<a<<"    "<<fn<<"    "<<mn;
```

This code is not giving desired results. I am just trying to ifstream 1st row contents.
is it posssible? Or i should store each set of data in different file (like names in one, ages in one, father names in one, mother names in other). Can you help?

Comment: ***is it posssible?*** Yes of course.

Comment: ***Or i should store each set of data in different file (like names in one, ages in one, father names in one, mother names in other).*** No need to do that.

Comment: `file>>setw(50)>>mn` is not going to work. You need to do the setw() on the output not the input. Also operator >>() will read to the first space.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064400/read-first-n-letters-from-file-to-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064400/read-first-n-letters-from-file-to-a-string)

Comment: Also related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127592/how-to-parse-text-based-table-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127592/how-to-parse-text-based-table-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read a file you don't have to specify that there is a gap in between values. Fstream does it for you. Any where there is spaces it won't read as one, for example the father's name Jack worn. It will only read Jack. Fstream reading has built in space delimited reading. So you will have to read the father's name and surname in different variables and also so for the mother. I did not test this code. This is based of my general knowledge so it might not be true.

```
string fn,fsn,mn,msn,n;
int a;
ifstream file("my.txt");
file >>n;       // Name
file >> a;      // Age
file >> fn;     // Father's name
file >> fsn;    // Father's surname
file >> mn;     // Mother's name
file >> msn;    // Mother's surname
cout << n << "   " << a << "    " << fn << ' ' << fsn <<"    " << mn << ' ' << msn;
```

Comment: but the name can have more than two strings my friend. How to keep a check of that?

Comment: ***name can have more than two strings*** If the # of items is the same for every person then you can use this method. if it is not you can't. I gave you links on your question about alternate methods.